# Adding Label, value and picture in Bootstrap's Typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing around with [Typeahead](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) and I am trying to figure out if there is a way to display Pictures and Labels in the search query as well? Something like how Twitter does when we try to mention users on Tweets.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After doing some research and pulling almost all my hair out, I finally figured out how to add Fullname, image and username to a typeahead like twitter.

Lets say this is the following structure of each object for your source,

```
{{ friend.id }}#{{ friend.username }}#{{ friend.imgurl }}#{{ friend.fullname }}
```

Then all you have to do is write a nice Highlighter, something like this

```
highlighter: function(item) {
              var parts = item.split('#'),
              html = '<div class="typeahead">';
              html += '<div class="media"><a class="pull-left" href="#"><img src='+parts[2]+' /></a>'
              html += '<div class="media-body">';
              html += '<p class="media-heading">'+parts[3]+' (@'+parts[1]+')'+'</p>';
              html += '</div>';
              html += '</div>';
              return html;
            },
```

This will easily add the Picture, Full name and Username in Typeahead.

Comment: I think you're missing a closing div here. But otherwise, works great.

Answer (score 8):

highlighter is not working anymore.

Use **templates**, example:

```
var my_friends = [
     {name: "John", picture: "http://..."}
    ,{name: "Mel", picture: "http://..."}
];

var friends = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: my_friends
});
friends.initialize();
$('#friend_name').typeahead(
    {
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1,
    },
    {
        name: 'friends',
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: friends.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            empty: 'not found', //optional
            suggestion: function(el){return '<img src="'+el.picture+'" />'+el.name}
        }
    }
);
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/jharding/9458780#file-custom-templates-js

Answer (score 7):

You will likely find it easier/better to use http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/ instead of trying to customise the default rubbish Bootstrap one!

If you search for Templating on that page, you'll find it - it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: can I still use my custom matcher and updater functions with it? I am actually trying to implement the @ triggered typeahead in a textarea, like Twitter.

Comment: It has it's own functions, but I suspect the syntax will be similar enough. Select2 can act as a typeahead rather than a select box if you pull in the stuff via ajax. To be honest I gave up on the bootstrap one pretty quick as I wanted typeahead across 20-30,000 items so needed to do the filtering on server instead of client.

Comment: lol okay. Well I finally figured out how to add the extra stuff for Bootstrap's Typeahead as well. So I think I am going to stick with that

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Honest question, why do you call it rubbish? `"...default rubbish Bootstrap..."`

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use the following customized code for rendering images containing with the JSON schema.

Please follow the [fiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shobhit_Sharma/vC4rd/) for implementation and testing.

The typeahead looks like:

```
    $(".typeahead").typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {

        //here we pass the query (search) and process callback arguments to the throttled function
        throttledRequest(query, process);

    },
    highlighter: function (item) {
        var test = testObjs[item];

        return '<div class="test">' + '<img src="' + test.photo + '" />' + '<br/><strong>' + test.name + '</strong>' + '</div>';
    },
    updater: function (selectedName) {

        //note that the "selectedName" has nothing to do with the markup provided
        //by the highlighter function. It corresponds to the array of names
        //that we sent from the source function.

        //save the id value into the hidden field
        $("#testId").val(testObjs[selectedName].id);

        //return the string you want to go into the textbox (the name)
        return selectedName;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
typeahead.initialize();
var typeahead = {

    typeaheadInit: function() {
        var jsonData = [{
            'id': 1,
            'name': 'Parajanov Museum',
            'image': 'img/1.png'
        }, {
            'id': 2,
            'name': 'Parajanov’s Movie',
            'image': 'img/2.png'
        }, {
            'id': 3,
            'name': 'S Parajanov’s about his series of Giocondas',
            'image': 'img/3.png'
        }, {
            'id': 4,
            'name': 'S Parajanov’s about the colore of pomegranate',
            'image': 'img/4.png'
        }, {
            'id': 5,
            'name': 'George Michael',
            'image': 'img/5.png'
        }];

        var productNames = [];
        $.each(jsonData, function(index, product) {
            productNames.push(product.name + "#" + product.image + "#" + product.id);
        });
        $('#typeahead').typeahead({
            source: productNames,
            highlighter: function(item) {
                var parts = item.split('#'),
                    html = '<div><div class="typeahead-inner" id="' + parts[2] + '">';
                html += '<div class="item-img" style="background-image: url(' + parts[1] + ')"></div>';
                html += '<div class="item-body">';
                html += '<p class="item-heading">' + parts[0] + '</p>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '</div></div>';

                var query = this.query;
                var reEscQuery = query.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
                var reQuery = new RegExp('(' + reEscQuery + ')', "gi");
                var jElem = $(html);
                var textNodes = $(jElem.find('*')).add(jElem).contents().filter(function() {
                    return this.nodeType === 3;
                });
                textNodes.replaceWith(function() {
                    return $(this).text().replace(reQuery, '<strong>$1</strong>');
                });

                return jElem.html();
            },
            updater: function(selectedName) {
                var name = selectedName.split('#')[0];
                return name;
            }
        });
    },

    initialize: function() {
        var _this = this;
        _this.typeaheadInit();
    }
};
```

Source: https://jsfiddle.net/geghamk/59eranrc/3/

Comment: that is simple and great answer, typeahead and jquery only :)